# webservice returning jagged array of ints

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have created a webservice and deployed it at http://reddyincv-001-site1.myasp.net/Webservice1.asmx it returns a jagged array of ints.

I am trying to consume it using silverlight, how do i store the retrieved values from the webservice and store it in a silverlight jagged array?

this is my code

```
private SampleService.WebService1SoapClient dataService = new SampleService.WebService1SoapClient();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataService.leftClickCompleted += new EventHandler<SampleService.leftClickCompletedEventArgs>(leftClick_Completed);
        dataService.leftClickAsync();

    }
    private void leftClick_Completed(object sender, SampleService.leftClickCompletedEventArgs e)
    {


        int[][] aaa = new int[14][];
        aaa = e.Result;

    }
```

Comment: How you are returning from web service..?Which Type it's returning..?

Comment: jagged array, int[14][];

Comment: Are you getting any exception.?

Comment: ya, at aaa= e.Results there is an error which says cant convert type string to int[][]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
aaa= e.Result.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

or

```
aaa= e.Result.YourResultType.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Edit:

That means you are returning string from web service,change the the Return type of the Web service of Type Jagged Array.

For Example : Your web service should be something  like

```
public int[][] GetResult()
{
   int[][] result = new int[14][];
   //add the recodrs to result

   return result;
}
```

Now in your application you can use like this

```
int[][] aaa=new aaa[14][];
aaa=e.Result;
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it did not work. For the second one aaa = e.Result.int[14][].Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray(); it says identifier expected.

Comment: Here YourResultType is not int[14][].whatever your return type of your web service.

Comment: Your return type of Web service is of type string.that's why you are getting exception cannot convert type string to int[][].Make sure your web service is returning jagged array.

Comment: [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public int[][] leftClick()
        {.... returns int[][] }   I think my webservice method returns int[][]. I am not sure what you say by "Make sure ur web server returns jagged array" how do i do that?

Comment: Looks your service is correct.and can you check after typing e.Result.leftClickResult here..?

Comment: http://erp90.com/pacman/img/Untitled.png This is a screen shot of e.result.l (I dont find leftClickResult)

Comment: Then try e.Result.ToArray();

Comment: error: Cant implicitly convert type char[] to int[][] :(

Comment: when you use this aaa= e.Result.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray(); what was the error..?see i don't know why your service returning string type.I fyour web service is returning int[][] then there is no need to cast the result.and check what you are getting in e.Result place a break point and check.